# Plot Arc Length Parametrization

Tags: plotting, parametric-functions, inverse, precision-and-accuracy

I want to plot the parametrization of the curve with respect to arc length. It is all known that we have to find the inverse of the arc length of the original function i.e. $F(t)$, and `S(t) =ArcLength[F[t],{t, 0, s }]`, while in my case the $F(t)$ is pretty complicated and hard to find the inverse $t = S^{-1}(s)$. $F(t)$ here is:

```
S[t_] := t(17Sqrt[17]+8Sqrt[15]t+10Sqrt[17]t^2)Sqrt[4913+544Sqrt[255]t+21180t^2+960Sqrt[255]t^3+15300t^4]/(289+16Sqrt[255]t+510t^2)
```

And when I put this inverse expression into the $F(s)$, the `InverseFunction[]` returns me nothing

```
In[]: InverseFunction[S[t]]

Out[]: InverseFunction[S[t]]
```

And this is the reason why my plot is also empty, I guess. Is there anybody can give me a help to solve the `InverseFunction[]` ?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please post code, not an image.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll modify my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can test `InverseFunction` for some values of $t$ by defining `u = InverseFunction[S]`.  If $u$ is a valid inverse, then `u[ S[t] ]` will give us $t$ back.  Consider this:

```
Clear[S]
S[t_] := t (17 Sqrt[17] + 8 Sqrt[15] t + 10 Sqrt[17] t^2) Sqrt[
    4913 + 544 Sqrt[255] t + 21180 t^2 + 960 Sqrt[255] t^3 + 
     15300 t^4]/(289 + 16 Sqrt[255] t + 510 t^2)

Clear[u]
u = InverseFunction[S];
With[{t = 1},
 {S[t], u[S[t]], S[u[S[t]]], t == u[S[t]]} // N]

(*  {34.5147, -1.36267, -34.5147, False}  *)
```

Here we have chosen $t=1$, calculated $S(1) = 34.5...$, but we got back $-1.36...$ for $t$ instead of 1.  We also consider $S(-1.36...)$ and that is not the same a $S(1)$.  So, `InverseFunction` cannot be used with our $S(t)$.

To obtain a numerical inverse of $S(t)$ we can use the following:

```
Clear[s, t, w]
soln = Solve[{S[t] == s, t > 0}, t, Reals] // Flatten;
w[s1_] := t /. soln /. s -> s1
With[{t = 1},
 {S[t], w[S[t]], t == w[S[t]]} // N]

{34.5147, 1., True}
```

In this case the function `w[s]` has returned the desired inverse.  We can also check the accuracy of this inverse with a quick plot of the difference between the input $t$ and the calculated inverse of $S(t)$:

```
Plot[Evaluate[t - w[S[t]]], {t, 0, 3},
 PlotPoints -> 541,
 PlotRange -> {All, 10^-15 {-3, 2}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!